# Find out which Style Resource a Control uses

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm searching for a way to find out which **style resources** a control uses.

I.e. I'm currently trying to change the `Brushes` of the back `Button` in my app.
Confusingly these brushes are partly located under the `ResourceKey`s `AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush` (etc.) instead of `BackButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush` (which doesn't seem to change anything - side question: what's this resource for?).

I couldn't find the the foreground theme brush resource for the normal `ViewState` at all.

So I'd love to know if there's some way or some website where I can see which resources a specific control uses. The Microsoft Docs have these informations for some controls but unfortunately they are incomplete and I didn't find anything about the `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle` (apart from the information that it should look like an AppBarButton which explains why it uses AppBarItem style resources - however that doesn't explain the existence of BackButton style resources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)You can get all styles in Pc **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design**
>
> 2)Install [XamlCandy](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/xaml-candy/8b9e2d69-feed-409c-befb-4ea97f97351a) app
>
> 3)Style for specific control
>
> -In Designer View https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JI2e.png
>
> -https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJabd.png and Press Ok
>
> -https://i.stack.imgur.com/V88rs.png

and you can change Winrt Default Control color by replacing color
  `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />`

Comment: thank you the file "themeresources.xaml" in the folder you mentioned contains the definition for the `NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle`.
For 3) I do know how to edit the style of a control. That wasn't the question ;)
1) and 2) seem very helpful though so thanks for that :)

Comment: weird the `ContentPresenter` of the back button style uses `AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush`
But the arrow remains black even after changing the color for given resource.
Any idea why?

Comment: If I set the Foreground property of Button to `{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}` it is displayed correctly although that should be the Foreground of this button anyway.