# Windows 8 Standard Theme Resources (StaticResource)

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I've just started developing apps for Windows 8. I have developed apps for Windows Phone.

In Windows Phone, there are many theme resources and styles predefined such as the ones you can find in the following link-

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/pre-defined-system-styles-and

I was wondering if there is something like this for Windows 8?

I did find this link-

http://www.win8tutorial.net/styling/windows-8-1-theme-resources/

But, it does not contain anything like "Font Families".

I want to use the light, semilight, bold font in my apps.
I could not find a direct way to use them.

Also, there aren't any standard font sizes
Are such resources not present in Windows 8?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014715/find-out-which-style-resource-a-control-uses/25017011#25017011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not defined for store apps.

But on the MSDN, you can find guidelines for [font usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700394.aspx), and an [overview of resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn518235.aspx).

They did provide complete styles for text, they just didn't split the parts up in separate resources.

Comment: saw all that before posting. :\  I guess I'll have to define my own resources.

Comment: @kshitijgandhi: Too bad indeed. No idea why they didn't just "spell it out", it's (a bit) annoying.

Comment: Not that its annoying, its easy to create styles for apps, but after developing for Windows Phone, I understand that such standard styles could be really helpful in designing standard & more beautiful apps.

Comment: That's the annoying part for me :) 
I'm also more used to developing phone apps, and the presence of the standard styles makes it easier to do "the right thing", so to say. But I agree, it's not a biggie.